# Achieve <pre> result without <pre> tag

Tags: css, pre

Is it possible to achieve this result, where the lines nicely touch each other:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
}

div pre {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="background_line"><pre>||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</pre></div>
<div class="background_line"><pre>||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</pre></div>
<div class="background_line"><pre>||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</pre></div>
<div class="background_line"><pre>||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</pre></div>
```

Without adding a `<pre>` element, so just with css styles.
Right now there is to much space when `white-space: pre;` is added in the css:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div>
<div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div>
<div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div>
<div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div>



<div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div><div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div><div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div><div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div>
```

If it would be possible then it would save me a lot of complexity.

Comment: Try font:caption

Comment: Lines "nicely touch each other", like `div.background_line { margin: -3px 0;
}` makes them overlap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just removing the `'Courier New'` looks like it gets you what you want:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div>
<div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div>
<div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div>
<div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div>



<div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div><div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div><div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div><div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div>
```

The original version with the `<pre>` has the user agent's stylesheet `font-family: monospace;` taking priority over your `font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the effect by using a negative `letter-spacing` combined with `margin-top`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  white-space: pre;
}

.background_line {
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
.background_line:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div>
<div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div>
<div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div>
<div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div>



<div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div><div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div><div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div><div class="background_line">||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the CSS.

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```